# How to find out who uploaded data in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there anyway I can find out that who upload files in S3 bucket when fetching files using Javascript API (listObjectsV2).

Comment: I need uploaded IAM user ID or Name on each file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no.  The listObjectsV2 API method doesn't expose this information.

API requests made to S3 can be logged using CloudTrail.

CloudTrail is able to capture events at the Management plane (i.e. changes to Bucket Properties) or at the Data plane (Object level events).

In order to find out who uploaded a file to S3 (`s3:PutObject` action) you would need to do the following:

- Ensure CloudTrail data events are enabled and configured to capture data events for the bucket in question
- Ensure your IAM user/role is authorised to query this data (from wherever you store it, usually another S3 bucket)

There is more information on how this can be achieved in the AWS docs.  The following two links are quite helpful:

[Logging Amazon S3 API calls using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html)
[How do I enable object-level logging for an S3 bucket with AWS CloudTrail data events?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html)

Comment: thank you very much, I will try this and let you know